# JRuby ActiveRecord/ActiveModel not creating methods and attributes for table columns (undefined method)

Tags: activerecord, jruby, activemodel

I am using JRuby 1.6.7, ActiveRecord 3.2.3, activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.2.2, activerecord-jdbcsqlanywhere-adapter-1.1.1  and the current Sybase JDBC4 driver.  Using a full Ruby On Rails application is not an option at this time.  I am getting the following error when I run my unit tests.

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_configuration_name' for #
      method_missing at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1687
      method_missing at /home/lynchcs/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27
```

I am able to perform a schema dump in my unit tests which correctly identifies the table.  Here is the schema for the table.

```
      create_table "THE_CONFIGURATION", :primary_key => "CONFIGURATION_ID", :force => true do |t|
        t.string "CONFIGURATION_GROUP", :limit => 32
        t.string "CONFIGURATION_TYPE",  :limit => 32
        t.string "CONFIGURATION_NAME",  :limit => 32
        t.string "CONFIGURATION_TEXT",  :limit => 7168
      end
```

Here is the model I built for it.

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'active_record'

    class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.table_name = 'SOART_CONFIGURATION'
      self.primary_key = 'configuration_id'
    end
```

Here is the class I used to manage my connections.  This class does successfully connect to the database and execute the query.

```
    require 'java'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'active_record'

    class ConnectionMaster
      def test_object
        "ARBITRARY"
      end

      def set_connection
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'jdbc' ,
        :driver => 'com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver' ,
        :url => 'jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.137.137:1111/MYAPP' ,
        :username => 'noneya' ,
        :password => 'noneya'
        )
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT 'ARBITRARY' AS ARBITRARY")
      end

      def clear_connections
        ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
      end

    end
```

It will error when "config = Configuration.find_by_configuration_name('test')" is executed.  If you comment out this line it will error out on  the "config.configuration_text" line.

```
      public void testRubyDatabaseQuery() {
        String theValue = "test";
        String jrubyCode =
        "require 'connection_master' \n"
        + "require 'configuration' \n"
        + "cm = ConnectionMaster.new \n"
        + "cm.set_connection \n"
        + "puts 'black cow of revenge' \n"
        + "config = Configuration.find(:all,:conditions => ['configuration_name=?','test']) \n"
        + "config = Configuration.find_by_configuration_name('test') \n"
        + "puts 'red cow of revenge' \n"
        + "cm.clear_connections \n"
        + "config.configuration_text \n";
        String executeValue = (String)JRubyMaster.execute(jrubyCode);
        this.assertEquals("executeValue and theValue do not match.", theValue, executeValue);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While building the question I found my own answer:)  I felt it was interesting enough to go ahead to post both question and answer.

In my first effort I used activerecord-jdbc-adapter and the problem was I was using "Configuration.find_by_configuration_name" and what it was building was "Configuration.find_by_CONFIGURATION_NAME"  the same for "config.configuration_text".  The column names where capitalized in the database and activerecord-jdbc-adapter created the methods with the capitalization.  Once that change was made it started throwing and invalid sql error due to the use of "LIMIT".

I then switched to using activerecord-jdbcsqlanywhere-adapter and it worked with "Configuration.find_by_configuration_name" and "config.configuration_text" but the unit test was then failing.  This was due to it building "returnValue[0]['arbitrary']"  rather than "returnValue[0]['ARBITRARY']"  despite that my query was "SELECT 'ARBITRARY' AS ARBITRARY".  activerecord-jdbcsqlanywhere-adapter is forcing everything to be lowercase.